# How can I solve the problem with "enable text compression" in Angular?

Tags: angular, optimization

I use a tool to test the performance of my web application and one of the issues that should be resolved is related to "enable text compression".My web application is developed using Angular.

Comment: If you are talking about content compression on the http response/request: Usually that is enabled on the web server, seeing as angular is client code that is the wrong place to try to enable this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.